# What is the purpose of std :: array<T, 0>?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I found that there is a template partial specialisation in std::array for `std::array<T, 0>`.

```
template <typename T>
struct array<T, 0> {
    //...
    typedef typename conditional<is_const<_Tp>::value, const char,
                                char>::type _CharType;
    struct  _ArrayInStructT { _Tp __data_[1]; };
    alignas(_ArrayInStructT) _CharType __elems_[sizeof(_ArrayInStructT)];
    //...
}
```

So what is the purpose of implementing `std::array<T, 0>`?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Reopened. The linked duplicate was a narrower question about the meaning `std::is_empty<std::array<T, 0>>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is, simply, uniformity. When you're writing templates it's much easier to be able to always write `std::array<Ty, N>` than to have to write a special case when `N` is 0. That kind of uniformity comes up often: `new int[0]`, `operator new(0)`, `std::malloc(0)`, `for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)` when `N` is 0.

Comment: But  *why* would one want to handle such special cases? What's so inherently broken with `std::array` that it needs specialisation for `N == 0` case? `size()` would return `0`, thus iterating would behave as expected (same as in your `for()` example). I can't think of any cases where the default implementation (that works for `N > 0`) would be broken.

Comment: @Fureeish because `T t[0];` isn't a valid member of a class, for all `T`